# Permission Denied cannot get location Android

Tags: android, geolocation, compass-geolocation, ip-geolocation, google-geolocation

I am providing permission to the application on Android at initial setup
to track geolocation and mobile lacs, cell id and country code along with tower code. I am receiving the following error on midway -  "Permission Denied cannot get location Android" i.e. initially on installation of the Application on android its providing geolocation initially but in the midway it stops fetching geolocation .

Solutions for the above will be really appreciated

Please Find the Code below -

```
private void requestStoragePermission() {
    Dexter.withActivity(this)
            .withPermissions(
                    Manifest.permission.WAKE_LOCK,
                    Manifest.permission.READ_CONTACTS,
                    Manifest.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE,
                    Manifest.permission.ACCESS_WIFI_STATE,
                    Manifest.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE,
                    Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION,
                    Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION)
            .withListener(new MultiplePermissionsListener() {
                @Override
                public void onPermissionsChecked(MultiplePermissionsReport report) {
                    // check if all permissions are granted
                    if (report.areAllPermissionsGranted()) {
                        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "All permissions are granted!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    }

                    // check for permanent denial of any permission
                    if (report.isAnyPermissionPermanentlyDenied()) {
                        // show alert dialog navigating to Settings
                        showSettingsDialog();
                    }
                }

                @Override
                public void onPermissionRationaleShouldBeShown(List<PermissionRequest> permissions, PermissionToken token) {
                    token.continuePermissionRequest();
                }
            }).
            withErrorListener(new PermissionRequestErrorListener() {
                @Override
                public void onError(DexterError error) {
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Error occurred! ", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
            })
            .onSameThread()
            .check();
}
```

Comment: Have you [requested location permissions](https://developer.android.com/training/permissions/requesting#perm-request) from the user?

Comment: yes i have allowed all the necessary permissions necessary beforehand

Comment: Including the pop-up prompts within the app itself? Just asking to clarify as it's not immediately clear in your question.

Comment: the pop up prompts are not included I am taking the location permissions initially & have cross checked that Location settings and permissions are all set.

Even the LAC and CID and Country codes are not fetching / stop midway

Comment: You need to **explicitly request** the location permission from the user **at runtime** as Location is classed as a [dangerous permission](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/permissions/overview#dangerous_permissions). Access to location information will be denied by Android otherwise, which is currently happening in your case.

Comment: the necessity of my application is to never ask for any permission from user after initial setup, How can i achieve it programmatically ?

Comment: If you've asked the user during initial setup, then `ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission()` should return `PERMISSION_GRANTED` for `ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION`, meaning you don't need to prompt the user again. If it does not return `PERMISSION_GRANTED`, then the user **has not** given you permission to access their location information, and you need to handle that accordingly.

Comment: After sometime in the midway when the app is running in background service its still throwing Permission Denied and I am getting PERMISSION_GRANTED

Comment: Have updated the Codebase Please Review

Comment: Please provide a solution

Answer (score 1):

Get location data then need to runtime permission try below code..

add things into your app if not present and also how to handle runtime permission.

Try this make sure your app level gradle file in compile sdk version latest. like

```
 compileSdkVersion 27
```

then after also add permission into android manifest file.

```
 <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
 <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" />
 <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />
```

and after check runtime permission like below make two method.

```
/** 
 * this method check permission and return current state of permission need. 

 */ 
private boolean checkPermissions() { 
int permissionState = ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this,
        Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION); 
return permissionState == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED;
 } 

/** 
* this method request to permission asked. 
*/ 
private void requestPermissions() { 
 boolean shouldProvideRationale =
        ActivityCompat.shouldShowRequestPermissionRationale(this,
                Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION); 

if (shouldProvideRationale) {
    Log.i(TAG, "Displaying permission rationale to provide additional context.");
} else { 
    Log.i(TAG, "Requesting permission");
    // previously and checked "Never ask again". 
    ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(MainActivity.this,
            new String[]{Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION},
            REQUEST_PERMISSIONS_REQUEST_CODE); 
  }  
 } 

  /** 
  * Callback received when a permissions request has been completed. 
  */ 
  @Override 
    public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, @NonNull String[] permissions,
                                   @NonNull int[] grantResults) {
Log.i(TAG, "onRequestPermissionResult");
if (requestCode == REQUEST_PERMISSIONS_REQUEST_CODE) {
    if (grantResults.length <= 0) {
        // If user interaction was interrupted, the permission request is cancelled and you 
        // receive empty arrays. 
        Log.i(TAG, "User interaction was cancelled.");
    } else if (grantResults[0] == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
        // Permission was granted. Kick off the process of building and connecting 
        // GoogleApiClient. 
        buildGoogleApiClient(); 
    } else { 
        // Permission denied. 

    } 
} 
}
```

then when call get location method then put like below check
in onCreateview method

```
 // Check if the user revoked runtime permissions.
if (!checkPermissions()) {
    requestPermissions();
}

buildGoogleApiClient();
```

Comment: These settings I have already implemented but In the midway I am getting the error  - Permission Denied

Comment: I am getting the locations Perfectly in the initial setup but unfortunately in the midway I am getting the error "permission-denied"

Comment: first you allow permission or not

Comment: Yes I have allowed permissions initially i.e. PERMISSION_GRANTED

Comment: check which permission denied.

Comment: Location Fetch Permission is denied and apart from that is there any other way to check the permission which is specifically denying ?

Comment: Have added the Location get code and permission please review

Comment: check make debug point into toast message for all permission granted.

Comment: Toast is shown when all permission is granted still I am getting the error

Comment: Please provide the solution